# Need to display rotation angle in unity Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am developing an unity scene for capturing the rotation values of the gameobject. So in my scene gameobject will be rotating dynamically and a text field will display the values of rotation. Now i need button in the scene which can capture that rotation value when clicked and perform the desired action. Please let me know how to achieve it. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you already tried and where you failed. This will improve your chances to get an answer to your question. Here you will find more information on [ask] a question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to display the euler angles (degrees) in the UI. First, you need to add a text object, like a [TextMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextMesh.html).
But the important part is to extract the rotation. You can get it from the Euler angles.

```
int rotationX = myGameObject.transform.eulerAngles.x;
int rotationY = myGameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y;
int rotationZ = myGameObject.transform.eulerAngles.z;
```

However, take in mind that the rotation displayed in the inspector will not necessarily 
match the real one. That is because the rotations are actually represented by Quaternions, and you can achieve a concrete rotation by several different angular combinations.

To set the text, first you need the reference to the varaible TextMesh and then you access to the field "text".

```
public TextMesh myText;

// rest of code...

myText.text = rotationX.ToString(); // or any other value...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you please tell me how to give value to the textMesh from the script? I am very new unity, please don't mind if this is a basic question

Comment: I edited the answer to include what you are asking me now.